# Slideshow controls jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slideshow im trying to make slide left and right when a control is clicked only im struggling.

The markup is...

Left
                
                    
                    
                    
                 
                right

```
            <div class="clear"></div>

            <div id="promotional-slide">
                <div class="cover">
                    <div class="promo-section one">
                      <span class="text-one">Buy the cheapest heating oil in the UK with our exclusive Web Oil Price Guarantee</span>
                      <span class="text-two">Your village</span>
                    </div>
                     <div class="promo-section two">


                    </div>
                    <div class="promo-section three">


                    </div>
                </div> <!-- end of div cover -->
            </div>  <!-- end of div promotional-slide -->
        </div>
```

And my jQuery is...

```
$('.scroll-right').click(function(){
    $('#promotional-slide .cover').animate({left:-640})  
});

$('.scroll-left').click(function(){
    $('#promotional-slide .cover').animate({left:640})  
});
```

Comment: The CSS is pretty important for this, could you post the section that deals with that, and tell us why it isn't working? Preferably if you post a jsfiddle of it; that'd lower the barrier to answer enough that somebody would be happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me if I add

```
#promotional-slide .cover {
    position: relative;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/84gGw/)

Comment: It jumps more than 640 px each way though?

Comment: Look at the jsFiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/84gGw/). Animation runs when add CSS position.